# jQuery POST to PHP hangs, causing unresponsive page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have the following JavaScript on my page:

```
$('#report_submit').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    if ( $('#email').val() == "" )
    {
        reportmessage('Please enter an e-mail address.');
        return false;
    }
    $.post('report.php',{method:reported,email:$('#email').val()},function(data){
        if (data == 'error')
        {
            reportmessage('Catastrophic failure. Please try again.');
        }
        if (data == 'email')
        {
            reportmessage('Check your e-mail address and try again.');
        }
        if (data == 'success')
        {
            $('#reportform').fadeOut();
            $('#reportsuccess').fadeIn();
            return true;
        }
    });
});
```

And report.php:

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    // Server side verification
    $method = trim(strip_tags(stripslashes($_POST['method'])));
    $email = trim(strip_tags(stripslashes($_POST['email'])));

    if (empty($method) OR empty($email))
    {
        echo 'error';
        exit;
    }

    if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false)
    {
        echo 'email';
        exit;
    }

    // Write it to the log
    $data = date('c').' - '.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].' - '.$email.' - '.$method."\n";

    file_put_contents ( 'reports.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND );

    echo 'success';
    exit;
}

?>
```

When the submit button is clicked, and there is a value in the e-mail address textfield, the page freezes almost instantly. I have to close/kill the process and reload the page. The JavaScript console shows nothing. I would assume the PHP script is running just fine; if I replace the script with `echo 'error';` the page works and I get the catastrophic error message. However, passing the POST variables directly to the script and not through AJAX shows the correct output in the browser.

It can't be a PHP issue, and the JavaScript should work fine (and does, when the PHP script returns a simple value without doing anything else). I've tested this page on my Mac in Chrome and Firefox, and on Windows in Firefox, Chrome, and IE. All freeze.

Is this a server configuration issue, and if so, what should I look for or change?

Comment: Is the PHP code executed? Do you see something appearing in reports.txt? What if you put some code before the if, does that execute?

Comment: check what your xmlhttprequest back to you using debugger

Comment: maybe its just cut off but i dont see where variable reported is coming from, if it a string then it should be 'reported'

Comment: add `echo "error";` to end of that php, after last `}`

Comment: @GolexTrol It appears as though none of the PHP code is being executed when requested over AJAX, but does execute when requested via HTTP. Nothing is being written to reports.txt.

@Jacob `reported` is a global variable updated by another function before the function I posted runs.

@eicto See above - over AJAX, it appears as though nothing runs.

Comment: Perhaps you should be a bit more explicit with your target URL, i.e. `/report.php` or `hostname+'/report.php'`. You might want to look at http://docs.jquery.com/API/1.1/AJAX#ajaxError.28_callback_.29 for debugging or http://docs.jquery.com/API/1.1/AJAX#.24.ajaxSetup.28_settings_.29 to handle errors.

Comment: @Flanery I just tested your code on my machine and it works fine using jquery 1.6.2. Maybe you have a problem in `reportmessage()`? I stubbed it using `alert()`. Or perhaps the `reported` variable is huge/not initialized properly. If you're using Chrome, you can check the request + response in the dev tools network panel: Wrench -> Tools -> Developer tools.

Comment: @banzaimonkey Bingo! I stuck an `alert(reported);` right before the AJAX call and found out it didn't have a value. Turns out I forgot to actually set it. If you want to submit an answer, I'll be glad to accept it as you led me to this discovery!